# Laravel Migrate: "Column Already Exists" 1060 Duplicate Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is a fresh laravel app that I am using to learn. There is no current table as this would be a fresh/first time migration. Why is it giving me this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name
> 'title' (SQL: create table `categories` (`id` bigint unsigned not null
> auto_increment primary key, `title` varchar(255) not null, `detail`
> varchar(300) not null, `image` varchar(255) not null, `title`
> varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at`
> timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
> 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('detail', 300);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cross-check your .env file settings for the database. Hope your database doesn't have this categories table.

Comment: It does not. In phpMyAdmin there is no 'categories' table and no 'categories' migration, however the error is indicating the 'title' column exists twice for some reason.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan optimize:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have updated the original table migration for the `categories` table then you need to either add the parameter fresh to your `php artisan migrate` command like this:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Be aware that that will remove all your data from the database.

And if you don't like that method then add `change()` add the end of `detail` field:

```
$table->string('detail', 300)->change();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. You should just look at the error keenly. It says ***duplicate column name 'title'***. You certainly tried to create this column twice, remove one and retry. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. For some reason when all I had to do was change 'detail' from string to text like this:

```
$table->string('detail', 300)
```

to

```
$table->text('detail', 300)
```

I don't understand why this worked, but it did.